# Student interest loan deduction during year with residence change

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Last year I moved from Texas (no state income taxes) to New York (state income taxes) in the middle of the year. I paid more in student loan interest than the $2500 maximum deduction, and when calculating adjustments to the federal income tax, I'm supposed to allocate how much of the student loan interest deduction took place in New York and how much in Texas.

My question is - if, for example, I paid $3500 - $1750 while living in New York and $1750 while living in Texas, can I allocate the $2500 as $1750 from New York and $750 from Texas, or does it need to be proportional to the total amount paid?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you are asking a question about taking a deduction for interest paid on your FEDERAL income taxes. As this is a federal question, the state you lived in at the time isn't important.

I don't see any deduction/credit for ne

Comment: No, the NY state tax form IT-201 wants your Federal AGI, and you apportion the fraction of your income derived as a resident of NY and from NY sources, and adjustments to the federal AGI again based on the fraction in each state.